# How use $scope between functions in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the variable between functions in one controller.
Controller:
app.controller { .......

```
$http.get("json.php")
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.m = response.p;
    $scope.licznikm = $scope.m.length;
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.openp = function (id, m) {
        ngDialog.open({
            template : 'formn.php',
            className : 'ngdialog-theme-default',
            backdrop : 'static',
        });
        $scope.name = m;
        $scope.id = id;
        console.log($scope.name); //is OK
        console.log($scope.id); // is OK
    };
    console.log($scope.miasta); //undefined
    console.log($scope.id); //undefined
```

Comment: As a side note `.success` is deprecated. You should just use `.then` and `.catch` for error handling.

Answer (score 2):

**the http call is asynchronous meaning the final logging code below will probably run before the http call has completed and the values have been set**. Simplest solution is to ensure you have the values before using them, this can be done by wrapping the code that uses them in a callback called after the http success. e.g.

```
$http.get("json.php")
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.m = response.p;
    $scope.licznikm = $scope.m.length;  
    $scope.date = new Date();  
    $scope.openp = function (id,m) {
        ngDialog.open({ 
            template: 'formn.php',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
            backdrop : 'static',
        });
        $scope.name = m;
        $scope.id = id;
        console.log($scope.name); //is OK
        console.log($scope.id);   // is OK
       // a callback fn
        useNewValues();
    };
});

function useNewValues() {
    // should be the vals from http response now
    console.log($scope.name);
    console.log($scope.id);
}
```

Comment: I would like to appeal to these variables globally example, in the view {{}}

Comment: is the view controlled by this controller? if so then perhaps you should wrap the assigment into the digest e.g.  $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.name = m; $scope.id = id; }); which will ensure the view is updated with the new vals once fetched, your view should have access to $scope vals but when you update them the view will not necessarily refresh

Comment: There is no need for `$scope.$apply` if the `$http` service is used. It may throw an exception is a digest cycle is already running. `$apply` is only needed when an action is used out of angulars scope, say a jQuery event. In this case the view should just update when the value from the server returns. If it isn't it points to an issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a promise and use it at any time to ensure code doesn't run until it has completed.

```
var have_data = $http.get("json.php")
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.m = response.p;
    $scope.licznikm = $scope.m.length;
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.openp = function (id, m) {
        ngDialog.open({
            template : 'formn.php',
            className : 'ngdialog-theme-default',
            backdrop : 'static',
        });
        $scope.name = m;
        $scope.id = id;
        console.log($scope.name); //is OK
        console.log($scope.id); // is OK
    });
 });
```

Then when you want to do anything else that requires you have actually retrieved the data just wrap it with the promise:

```
have_data.then(function() {
    console.log($scope.id);
});
```

If the data has been fetched the function will execute almost immediately, if it hasn't yet arrived it will execute as soon as data does arrive.

You can re-use the have_data promise this way as many times as you need.

Comment: I would like to use $scope.id globally in the controller so that other functions could use it as a parameter

Comment: Just move all of the code that references it inside the `have_data.then` function. Anything outside it will execute before the data arrives. From inside that callback you can safely use it as a parameter to call other functions. From outside it you can check it for `undefined`, or in a view you can wrap your html with `ng-if` but it won't be set until after your controller body has finished executing.